# Detecting click on window scrollbar

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to pause the main window scroll when scrolling a table, which I've done but are having trouble enabling the main window scroll again after.

This function will pause the main window scroll when scrolling over table.

```
function preventWindowScroll() {

  scrollTable = document.querySelector(".members-data");

  if (scrollTable.contains(event.target)) {

var oldScrollPos = document.body.scrollTop;

window.onscroll = function () { window.scrollTo(0, oldScrollPos); };

  } else {
   // disable scrollTo in order to reenable main window pause
    window.onscroll = function () {};
  }
}
```

The problem is that if I try to scroll down by clicking and dragging the main window scrollbar it's still jammed by scrollTo.
I've tried doing an onclick event, but it doesn't work when clicking scrollbar.

```
  document.body.onclick = function(e) {

  scrollTable = document.querySelector(".members-data");

  if (!scrollTable.contains(e.target)) {
   window.onscroll = function () {};
  }
};
```

I've also tried removing the event listener, but can't figure out where to put it.

```
 document.body.removeEventListener('mousewheel', preventWindowScroll);
 document.body.removeEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', preventWindowScroll);
```

If I could just detect when a user clicks on the main window scroll eit would work as intended.

note: I have achieved pausing the main window scroll other ways, but they all have slight drawbacks.

Thanks

Comment: Highly doubt there is a way to detect they click on the scrollbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this code. Works in Chrome.

```
yourTable.addEventListener('wheel', handleMouseScroll);

function handleMouseScroll(e) {

  var delta = e.deltaY || e.detail || e.wheelDelta;

  if (delta < 0 && this.scrollTop == 0) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  if (delta > 0 && this.scrollHeight - this.clientHeight - this.scrollTop <= 1) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this wont work on a table with overflow-y scroll on the tbody tag. Which I have.

Comment: Maybe if add this listener to tbody tag it would work?

Comment: Holy Moly!! It works!! Why didn't I think of that. Thanks Max I'll mark this answer as correct because it works with your code while adding the event listener to the tbody instead. :)

Comment: Thank you too, I'm glad I've helped you :)